# StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java

he intentado hacerle click a el botón a través de diferentes xpath, el que tiene al momento es un localizador único, sin embargo sigue dando el error que les comento en el título. 
He intentado hacerlo de diferentes formas y aún no lo consigo. 
Gracias si pueden ayudarme.

public class SelectPrice extends BaseClass {

```
public SelectPrice(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

// SELECT PRICE

By homePriceLocator = By.id("ryanair-logomark");
By fromPriceLocator = By.xpath("//div[@class='flight-header__min-price hide-mobile']");
By standardLocator  = By.xpath("//flights-table-price[@flight='::$ctrl.flight' and @class='show-mobile']");
By continueLocator  = By.id("continue");
By bagPageLocator   = By.xpath("//span[@translate='trips.seats.modal.skip']");

public void ChoosePrice() {

    if (isDisplayed(homePriceLocator)) {

        click(fromPriceLocator);

    } else {
        // System.out.println("Price is not available");
    }

    click(standardLocator);
}

public boolean BagPage() {
    return isDisplayed(bagPageLocator);

}
```

}

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the spanish version of SO, you must translate your question to the lenguage of this site or your question will be removed. Furthemore i recommend you to share the code not a image. :)

Comment: ¿Por casualidad aparece la linea en el que te da exception?

Comment: Sí, en justamente en el click(fromPriceLocator); Es decir cuando busca el botón fromPriceLocator .